# What is the ViewPagerAdapter Lifecycle esp. instantiateItem(View collection, int position)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not clear on the Lifecycle of ViewPagerAdapter.  In particular when is instatiateItem(View view, int position) called?  Not using fragments, and I really need to set the adapter on the returned view at  some point.  Where can I do this?  Whats happending now is that I am calling setItem(id) on the view pager and I am ending up with instantiateView(..) being called once for each View the ViewPager supports every time. So its always returning the last view, in the last position.